# Is Visual Studio 2012 faster than 2010 in design view?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I currently use Visual studio 2010 and it is very slow in design view when a page has a lot of controls.  For example changing a property on a control in a big page can show the spin wheel (hourglass) for 5 to 10 seconds!

I heard that VS-2012 was faster but will it be faster in this particular case?  I'm ready to upgrade to VS-2012 if it will improve the speed in design view.

Does someone here made the switch to VS-2012 and saw a speed improvement in design view?

I'm running a i7-8gb with Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: Design view for ...? WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net? Something else? There are a number of different technologies for which VS provides a design time experience, and which probably share very little code. It's possible that some improved, some stayed the same, some may even be slower.

Comment: Ooops... Forgot to mention...  My question is for ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the design view quite a bit faster with XAML and WinForms, so I would guess there were also improvements made to the ASP.NET designer. YMMV.